# Prove that $A_n^{\bullet}=A_n \backslash (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1})$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

Definition of **Lebesgue Outer Measure**: Given a set $E$ of $\mathbb R$, we define the **Lebesgue Outer Measure** of $E$ by, $$m^*(E) = \inf \left\{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \ell(I_n): E \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}I_n \right\}$$ where $\ell(I_n)$ denotes the length of interval (bounded and nonempty interval).

Definition of **measurable set**: A set $E$ measurable if $$m^*(T) = m^*(T \cap E) + m^*(T \cap E^c)$$ for every subset of $T$ of $\mathbb R$.

**My question:** If $A_n$ is measurable for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is it true that $A_n^{\bullet}=A_n \backslash (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1})$,  is measurable, for $n \geq 2$?

I proved that the finite union of measurable sets is measurable and that the measure of the union is the sum of the measures if they are pairwise disjoints. I don't know if that helps anything.

Comment: Show that if $A$, $B$ are measurable, then the set $A \setminus B$ is also measurable (it's not too bad). From this it will follows that the set you have above will be measurable.

Comment: I think it's more simple. Note that $A \backslash B=A \cap B^c=(A^c \cup B)^c$. So, if the complement is measurable (trivial) and the finite union is measurable, then $A \backslash B$ is measurable and the results follows.